# PHP / mySQL - prepare and bind locally

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, bind

If I do prepare/bind, then do execute, that will be two trips to the server.

I need the quoting/escaping functionality + security features, but I don't want two trips to the server.

None of my queries will be re-executed on the same channel, so I have no performance saving.

Is there not some "local" implementation that takes a parameterised sql string and creates SQL that can be sent + executed once?

In other words, a local implementation of prepare+bind that is not done on the mysql server?

Or am I not seeing the big picture?

thx.

Comment: PDO has this functionality. However, in this case the whole sql statement is sent at the same time, making your code again vulnerable to sql injection. So, you really need to know what you are doing. Your question is basically: I do not want to use prepared statements, how to prevent sql injection in this case?

Comment: PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES However this means if the query is going to go bang, it goes bang in the `->execute()` instead of the `->prepare()`

Comment: and that it is not safe from sql injections any longer...

Comment: @Shadow that's but a delusion

Comment: that will be two trips to the server. Well yes but don't forget that it doesn't use http protocol or another slow protocol. So you get a connection from you connection pool which is probably already connected. The overhead is so minimal.

Comment: @SanderVisser connection has nothing to do here.

Comment: The connection pool is a bit unrelated. But the performance loss for two trips to server is neglect-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to get it with mysqli prepared statements.

However, PDO offers you [such a functionality](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation), which, despite the widespread delusion, is perfectly safe.